# Office 2003 PIA Prerequisite in the .Net framework and Office 2007

Tags: .net, office-2007

What happens when the Office 2003 PIA prerequisite and launch condition in a Windows installer are run against an Office 2007 system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will fail unless for the simple reason that Office 2003 is not installed. We create separate installers for Office 2007 and Office 2003.

Also, there is a difference in the structure of Office 2003 add-ins versus Office 2007 add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 2003 PIA require Office 2003 be installed (so I'm guessing it would fail). AFAIK, the 2003 interops won't work with the 2007 applications. More information about these types of scenarios can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/andreww/archive/2007/06/08/why-is-vs-development-not-supported-with-multiple-versions-of-office.aspx). So even if it did install (pretty easy to test) you might not have a working application.

Are you trying to get some 2003 Add-ins to work with Office 2007?